# Как правильно организовать обработку исключение в MVC в Java?

Tags: java, mvc, исключения

Имеется структура каталогов, разработанная на основе `MVC`, и имеет вид (другие каталоги исключены для наглядности и понимания сущности происходящего):

```
model/dao/AccountDao.class
util/AesCrypt.class
```

Имеется класс `AesCrypt`, содержащий метод `encrypt(String password)`, который занимается шифрованием и дефишрованием пароля:

```
public String encrypt(String password) throws CryptException {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(VECTOR.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

            return new String(Hex.decodeHex(password.toCharArray()));
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException | DecoderException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Cant' create a crypt.");
            throw new CryptException("Can't create a crypt.", e);
        }
    }
```

Как вы можете заметить, внутри имеется обработка возможных исключений.
В классе `AccountDao` имеется метод `create(Account account, String password)`, который внутри себя занимается шифрованием пароля, переданного в данный метод, для последующего помещения зашифрованного пароля в БД. Внутри данного метода нужно будет вызвать метод шифрования пароля `create(Account account, String password)` того самого `AesCrypt` и выглядит это дело так (лишний код заменен на комментарии):

```
@Override
    public boolean create(Account account, String password) throws DaoException {
        // ... code
        AesCrypt crypt = utilProvider.getAesCrypt();
        
        try {
            // ... code
            String cryptPassword = crypt.encrypt(password);  // тут должна быть обработка исключений

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Couldn't create an account in the database: {}.", account);
            throw new DaoException("Couldn't create an account in the database " + account);
        } 
        
        // ... code
    }
```

В строке `String cryptPassword = crypt.encrypt(password);` должна быть обработка исключений.

**Вопрос** - опять повторно нужно обрабатывать исключения или как правильно организовать код? Получится, что в двух разных классах будет дублирование кода, который обрабатывает исключения.

Comment: пароль должен шифроваться до вызова DAO слоя - в слое бизнес логики. DAO работает только с БД, а Вы пытаетесь туда запихнуть то что не касается работы с БД.

Comment: Спасибо за указание на ошибку, исправил у себя. Но сущность вопроса остается актуальной.

Comment: В `AesCrypt` не нужен `try...catch`. Пробрасывайте ошибку туда, откуда вызвали метод и там же разбирайтесь . Но если возникла ошибки, то пользователь не должен быть создан и на UI должно быть сообщение об серверной ошибке (500 статус ответа)

Comment: @Tsyklop, благодарю за ответ. Всё таки там столько много исключений выбрасывается: `catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException | DecoderException e)`, их нужно все пробрасывать дальше? И они, вроде как, "внутренние", то есть "принадлежат" `AesCrypt`'у.
Напишите его в ответах, если считаете его полным, чтобы я его принял как ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: Можно сделать обработку через перехватчики исключений (interceptors).

Answer (score 0):

> В строке String cryptPassword = crypt.encrypt(password); должна быть обработка исключений.

Не обязательно, а в этом случае, скорее всего, не нужна. Обработку исключений нужно делать там, где это имеет смысл, а именно там, где клиент получивший исключение, может что-то осмысленное с ним сделать.

Примеры, когда можно что-то сделать:

1. ошибка соединения с сетью - можно попробовать опять после паузы
2. ошибка во входных данных предоставленных пользователем - можно и нужно попросить ввести данные заново

В вашей же ситуации, если функция `create(Account account, String password)` получит, скажем, `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, она ничего сделать не может. Это ошибка программиста и нет никакой возможности *на этом уровне* обработать такие исключения, вызванные ошибкой программиста. Правильное решение это сделать `CryptException` runtime исключением, и не обрабатывать его в этом месте вообще. В крайнем случае завернуть в `DaoException`, если у вас по контракту, все исключения из DAO слоя заворачиваются в `DAOException`.

Обработка этого исключение будет в обобщенном виде на уровне контроллера, там где он ловит все исключения, и в зависимости от типа возвращает соответствующий http status, если это web приложение.